# Permuting roots in splitting fields

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Currently, I've just started to study Field and Galois theory. In one of my textbooks, I have found the following (probably important) theorem:

If $K/F$ is a splitting field for the irreducible polynomial $f \in F[X]$ and $a,b \in K$ are two roots of $f$, then there is an automorphism in $\text{Aut}(K/F)$ which sends $a$ to $b$.

The proof is omitted in my textbook, so I try to find it by myself. I know how to show that there is an isomorphism $\tau:F(a) \to F(b)$ sending $a$ to $b$ and being the identitiy when restricted to $F$. To complete the proof, it seems to be necessary to show that $\tau$ can be extended to an isomorphism $\sigma:K \to K$. My problem: I have no idea how to show that a suitable $\sigma$ exists. My question: How to show this?

The textbook is "Basic Abstract Algebra" by Schilling (1975) and the theorem is called "Proposition" and can be found in chaper 8, section 8.5.

Comment: I think that you first have to prove your initial result in a more general setting. If $ F_{1} $ and $ F_{2} $ are isomorphic fields and $ f \in {F_{1}}[X] $ is irreducible, then $ f $ transfers to an irreducible $ g \in {F_{2}}[X] $. Let $ a $ be a root of $ f $ in a splitting field $ K_{1} $ of $ f $ over $ F_{1} $ and $ b $ a root of $ g $ in a splitting field $ K_{2} $ of $ g $ over $ F_{2} $. Then you can show that $ {F_{1}}(a) $ and $ {F_{2}}(b) $ are isomorphic by slightly modifying your proof. Finally, iterate this process until you have an isomorphism between $ K_{1} $ and $ K_{2} $.

Comment: @BerrickFillmore: I already thought about induction but I do not see how this should exactly work. Is it your idea to do something like this: Take a two additional roots $c,c'$ of $f$ and then show that there is an isomorphism $F(a)(c) \to F(b)(c')$ extending $\tau$ (and if this works, repeat the process until you reach $K$)?

Comment: Yes. I know that $ F(a) $ and $ F(b) $ aren’t exactly the same sub-field of $ K $, but they’re isomorphic and your initial result applies to fields that are isomorphic, not just the same. Hence, you can take roots $ c,d \in K $ that are not equal to $ a $ or $ b $ and then construct an isomorphism from $ F(a)(c) $ to $ F(b)(d) $. Do this until you reach $ K $.

Comment: Ok. But then my problem is as follows: I think in order to use your argument, it is somehow necessary to find a polynomial $p$, irreducible over $F(a)$, such that $p(c)=0$ and $p'(d)=0$ where $p'$ denotes the image of $p$ under the isomorphism $F(a)\to F(b)$. Or I am wrong? If not, how to show that a suitable polynomial $p$ exists?

Comment: At each induction step, you will need to take an irreducible factor of the polynomial.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Thank you!

Comment: Hi russoo. I just made my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might as well make my comments into an answer. Let $ S(n) $ denote the following statement:

> For any two fields $ F $ and $ F' $, any polynomial $ f \in F[X] $ of degree $ n $ and any splitting field $ E $ of $ f $ over $ F $, if there exists a field isomorphism $ \varphi: F \to F' $, then for any splitting field $ E' $ of $ \varphi(f) $ over $ F' $ (where $ \varphi(f) $ is the polynomial in $ F'[X] $ obtained by replacing each coefficient of $ f $ by its image under $ \varphi $), there exists an extension of $ \varphi $ to an isomorphism $ \tilde{\varphi}: E \to E' $.

We implicitly assume in the statement above that with a splitting field comes a field embedding of the base field into it.

Clearly, $ S(1) $ is true, so let us assume that $ S(n) $ is true for some $ n \in \Bbb{N} $.

Let $ f \in F[X] $ have degree $ n + 1 $. Let $ p $ be an irreducible factor (over $ F $) of $ f $. Then extend $ \varphi $ to a field isomorphism $ \tilde{\varphi}: F(\alpha) \to F'(\beta) $, where $ \alpha $ is a root of $ p $ in $ E $ and $ \beta $ is a root of $ \varphi(p) $ in $ E' $. Hence, there now exists a $ g \in F(\alpha)[X] $ such that
$$
f                  = (X - \alpha) \cdot g \quad \text{and} \quad
\tilde{\varphi}(f) = (X - \beta)  \cdot \tilde{\varphi}(g).
$$
Note that $ E $ and $ E' $ remain splitting fields of $ g $ and $ \tilde{\varphi}(g) $ over $ F(\alpha) $ and $ F'(\beta) $ respectively. The induction hypotheses thus hold, and as $ \deg(g) = n $, we can extend $ \tilde{\varphi} $ to a field isomorphism
$$
\tilde{\tilde{\varphi}}: E \to E'.
$$
As $ \tilde{\tilde{\varphi}} $ obviously extends $ \varphi $, we deduce that $ S(n + 1) $ is true.

By mathematical induction, $ S(n) $ is true for all $ n \in \Bbb{N} $.

Answer (score 1):

A useful result for you might be the [Isomorphism Extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_extension_theorem).  You can find a detailed proof, IIRC, in Dummit & Foote (or by Googling).  This theorem states the following:

Let $F$ be a field and $E$ a finite extension of $F$.  Suppose we have a field isomorphism $\phi:F \rightarrow F'$.  Letting $\overline{F'}$ denote an algebraic closure of $F'$, we can extend $\phi$ to an isomorphism $\tau$ from $E$ to a subfield of $\overline{F'}$ wherein $\tau|_F = \phi$.

Comment: Thank you! I now see that the extension theorem can indeed be used to complete the proof which I was asking for. (Although I prefer the proof suggested by Berrick Fillmore in the comments since it avoids Zorn's Lemma.)

Comment: I'm glad I could help!  Also, knowing that the Galois group of an irreducible polynomial acts transitively on its roots is indeed an important fact.  For one, if you're trying to determine the Galois group of a polynomial, it lets you restrict yourself to looking at transitive subgroups of $S_{\deg(f)}$.  Another instance that I can think of where it's been useful for me in the past is when searching for a generator of the Galois group of a cyclotomic extension.